# Load a matrix from a .mm file into Python

Tags: python

I am trying to load/run a matrix from a test.mm file in python using Numpy. The matrix inside the file is written for example a 2x2 Matrix as

```
    1 1 10
    1 2 11
    2 1 20
    2 2 30
```

I researched a lot, but I couldn't find a suitable answer.

Comment: What is an mm file? How is it created?

Comment: Okay I just found out, that its a Matrix Market file, a so called coo_Matrix which can be loaded with" scipy.io.mmread". I have still the problem to make a Numpy matrix out of that.

Comment: If it returns a sparse matrix, you can just use `.A` to get the dense array

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: What should I do when someone answers my question?. But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

The code is propably not the best ever, but it works on the example you provided. 
Also in python indexes starts with 0, you have indexes 1,2 which supposes 3x3 matrix. I modified it though for your usecase

```
import numpy as np

def mm2matrix(file_name,start_line = 1):
    with open(file_name,'r') as f:
        data = f.read().split('\n')
    number = [i.split(' ') for i in data]
    number = number[start_line:]
    all_numbers = []
    for i in range(len(number)):
        all_numbers += [float(sub) for sub in number[i] if len(sub)!=0]


    mmfile = np.array(all_numbers).reshape(len(all_numbers)/3,3,)
    x_index = mmfile[:,0].astype(np.int)-1
    y_index = mmfile[:,1].astype(np.int)-1 # you say 2x2 matrix, but you have indexes 1,2
    matrix = np.zeros(shape = [np.amax(x_index)+1,np.amax(y_index)+1])
    values = mmfile[:,2]
    matrix[x_index,y_index]=values

    return matrix

matrix = mm2matrix('test.mm')
>>> matrix
array([[10., 11., 22.],
       [20., 45., 85.]])
```

**test.mm** - I added one more column (2x3 or 3x2) for testing purpouses

```
Matrix
1 1 10
1 2 11
1 3 22
2 1 20
2 2 30
2 2 45
2 3 85
```

if the array has switched axes, then just transpose it

```
matrix = matrix.T
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have onn questions left. My first row in the file is a title "Matrix". how do I start from the second line?